# How below expression will be evaluated in C?

Tags: c

I was debugging a C code and came across below expression. I want to know, 
how below expression will be evaluated in c?

x += y*2 != z;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To figure out expressions like that start with the [precedence table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence):

- Multiplication has precedence of 3, so it will be evaluated first
- `!=` has precedence of 7, so it will be evaluated next
- `+=` has precedence of 14, so it will be evaluated last.

Therefore, `x` will be incremented by `1` if `y*2` is not equal to `z`.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
x += ((y*2) != z);
```